# Jquery AutoSugggets Plugin for Multiple Values

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery

I was looking for some Jquery Plugin which have multiple auto suggest option (example can be found [here](http://www.propertyfinder.ae/en/buy.html)). I need second value to be populated on the basis of first one selected. Like I select Country as first one the second auto suggest may be cities of that. Any idea please? Some solution similar to this one or how can we do that in Jquery.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

I needed the same thing and didn't find any jquery plugin that could'n help ,so the solution i came up with was :

1. populate the first drop down list.
   when a user change the selected default value of the first drop down list:
2. empty the other Drop down lists.
3. call an ajax method to retrieve the needed data for the secondary drop down list.
4. populate the secondary drop down list with the data retrieved from the ajax method.
5. do the same for the other drop down lists.

HTML:

```
 <select id="ddl1" />
 <select id="ddl2" />
```

JS:

```
$("#" + ddl1).change(function () {
    getddl2values(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any plugin for that. I suggest to write this yourself.

- specify n SELECTboxes with JS change handlers.
- when SELECT changes you generate 'filter block' with X in other div.
- When you click X, you reset value of SELECT to 0 and remove 'filter block'.
- when you change previously selected value you find proper filter block by generated ID which is similar to SELECT ID.

I think this code should be pretty easy.

**Edit:** I didn't read the whole question, my bad... After you change some selectboxes you should generate options of dependent selectboxes first. It depends how you want to store data. This can be made by changing OPTIONs on AJAX "success" called when SELECT onchange appear.

**Edit2:**
You CAN do it in single box:

```
<div id="filters"> </div>

<select id="country">
<option></option>
...
</select>

<select id="price">
<option></option>
...
</select>
```

Then you write event handlers in jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $("select").change(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    if($(this).val()==0){ // if you choose default/zero value
      $("#filter-"+id+).remove();
    }
    else if($("#"+id+"-filter").length > 0){ // if you only update value
       $("#filter-"+id).html($(this).val()+'<span>X</span>');
    } else { // add filter box
      $("#filters").append('<div id="#filter-'+id+'">'+$(this).val()+'<span>X</span></div>');
    }
  });
  $("#filters > div > span").live("click", function(){
    var select_id = $(this).attr('id').substring(7);
    $("#".select_id).val(0);
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
});
```

I wrote this in a hurry but if you know how to write in jQuery you should get the point even if I did some mistakes.

Comment: thank you for your reply. But the problem is that I want to do it in a single box like in the example link I had in my question with out using Select list.

Comment: Is this what you were looking for?